# How to properly combine multithreading and multiprocessing?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm using a Python program which basically reads and fits an observed curve, for context, the light spectrum of many stars, applying spectrum models so I can retrieve parameters such as the mean age of this group of stars, and save them to a file.
I need to apply this program over many spectra while additionally calculating errors using Monte Carlo simulations, which means each fit or calculation has to be done x100. In summary, my program takes a lot of computing power and time. Therefore, I'm trying to implement multiprocessing and multithreading in the code and optimize the mechanism to make it as fast as possible.
I don't know much and that's why I'm here. I would like to know what are some common implementations that could help my program. I read that multiprocessing is used mainly in CPU-bound tasks, and so I was thinking of creating a pool processes for the Monte Carlo simulations. Maybe you can give me some more tips.

Answer (score 1):

Python has no multithreading support, thanks to GIL (global interpreter lock).

You might be looking for multiprocessing solution, since you won’t gain much from async (you’re doing a lot of computations which is not IO related).

There’s the library multiprocessing, and you might consider task query mechanism such as RabbitMQ, if you have multiple servers, for scale.